# Configure fiddler to listen only my site

Tags: fiddler

I downloaded [fiddler4](http://fiddler2.com/get-fiddler) built on `.NET4`.  When I run this application it shows me entire traffic that takes place in my browsers/apps.  I tired the following 2 ways:

1. http://ipv4.fiddler:2133/
   http://localhost.:2133/Default.aspx  [Added .]
   This opens my site, but site fiddler shows other traffic.
2. I tried to use **filter** tab in it.  But the configuration it little complex for me.

[image]

Please share your suggestion about a *better approach in configuring fiddler to listen only a particular site*, sorry for this newbie type question, I also checked the answers of @ericlaw but couldn't get it.

If possible please direct me to some reference with screenshots will be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the **Filters** tab, in the box under **Show only the following hosts**, replace what you've typed with just **localhost**, without the `http://` prefix.

Comment: +1 Thought there is going to a big configuration changes.  Too simple I love this, thanks for fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the prefix as Eric suggested, but I think that you should keep the port (it still works without port). So the configuration is something like this:
[image: example-configuration]

And then, you click on `Actions -> Run Filterset now` to start filtering. One thing to note is that to capture requests from Chrome/Firefox, you need to uncheck `Show only Internet Explorer traffic`. On the left panel is some requests from `http://localhost:8081`